# Plural forms which end in -x such as tableaux

Tags: grammatical-number, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Words borrowed from French and ending in `-eau` originally had plural forms which appended an `-x` rather than an `-s`. For e.g., the plurals of *tableau*, *beau*, and *plateau* were *tableaux*, *beaux*, and *plateaux* respectively. While the [use of](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tableaux,tableaus,plateaux,plateaus&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) *plateaux* and *beaux* has petered out in favour of *plateaus* and *beaus*, *tableaux* has not.

My questions:

1. How are these `-x` plural forms pronounced?
2. Is there any particular reason why *tableaux* is still the preferred plural form unlike *plateaux*, *beaux*, and *portmanteaux*?

Comment: The first part is [General Reference](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tableau?q=tableaux) although that was a surprise to me. I'd never pronounce the x, I'd say it like French.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hence my question.

Comment: Unlike Andrew, I would pronounce *tableaux* with a *z* sound at the end.  And my English-speaking listeners should understand with no trouble.

Comment: Like GEdgar, I'd pronounce it with a final /-z/, too, in English, unless I were quoting or practicing or playing with French. But I'd spell it _tableaus_. Oh, and as for why -- every word in a language has a different history in the mind of every speaker of that language. That means there are a lot of reasons why, and enough of them converged to exceed the expectation boundary. It's an evolutionary process, and trying to answer _why_ certain particular forms survive is like trying to decide _why_ only those two rats in that particular litter survived to breed.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, but that's the same as pronouncing the anglicised _tableaus_, which is how most of the other candidates are spelt in English. The -x in the French spelling of _tableaux_ is silent.

Comment: Both COCA and NGrams disagree with you as to beaux/beaus.

Comment: @StoneyB From the looks of it, most of the _beaux_ in COCA refer to _Beaux Arts_. While Ngrams is case-sensitive, its results are not and it's tough to verify matters. But you're right in that the use of _beaux_ is still prevalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED attests as occurring in English texts the following irregular *-x* noun plurals:

- aboideau > aboideaux
- bandeau > bandeaux
- bateau > bateaux
- bayou > bayoux
- beau > beaux
- bijou > bijoux
- bordereau > bordereaux
- bureau > bureaux
- château > châteaux
- chou > choux
- damoiseau > damoiseaux
- fabliau > fabliaux
- fricandeau > fricandeaux
- jeu > jeux
- lambeau > lambeaux
- maquereau > maquereaux
- morceau > morceaux
- Pineau > Pineaux
- plateau > plateaux
- portmanteau > portmanteaux
- procès verbal > procès verbaux
- réseau > réseaux
- rouleau > rouleaux
- seau > seaux
- tableau > tableaux
- taureau > taureaux
- torteau > torteaux
- Tourangeau > Tourangeaux
- trumeau > trumeaux
- vœu > vœux

Most of those are far too rare to be considered anything other than unassimilated, but of those that aren’t, the Ngrams do not bear out the OP’s assertion that the *-x* forms have fallen by the wayside.  In fact, only the very oldest ones have been superseded by *-s* forms.

---

## Divination by Ngram

In the following Ngrams, the *-x* spelling is in blue and the *-s* spelling is in red.  Notice how the blue nearly always dominates.

---

### [*bateaux* vs *bateaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bateaux%2Cbateaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *bateaux* vs *bateaus* ngram]

### [*beaux* vs *beaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beaux%2Cbeaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *beaux* vs *beaus* ngram]

### [*bijoux* vs *bijous*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bijoux%2Cbijous&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *bijoux* vs *bijous* ngram]

### [*bureaux* vs *bureaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bureaux%2Cbureaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *bureaux* vs *bureaus* ngram]

### [*châteaux* vs *châteaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chateaux%2Cchateaus%2Cch%C3%A2teaux%2Cch%C3%A2teaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *châteaux* vs *châteaus* ngram]

### [*jeux* vs *jeus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jeux%2Cjeus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *jeux* vs *jeus* ngram]

### [*morceaux* vs *morceaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=morceaux%2Cmorceaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *morceaux* vs *morceaus* ngram]

### [*plateaux* vs *plateaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plateaux%2Cplateaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *plateaux* vs *plateaus* ngram]

That one is interesting because it is one of the few that shows a distinct difference depending on whether the “British” or “American” corpus has been selected.

[**British *plateaux* vs *plateaus***](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plateaux%2Cplateaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)
[image: British *plateaux* vs *plateaus* ngram]

[**American *plateaux* vs *plateaus***](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plateaux%2Cplateaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
[image: American *plateaux* vs *plateaus* ngram]

### [*portmanteaux* vs *portmanteaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=portmanteaux%2Cportmanteaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *portmanteaux* vs *portmanteaus*]

### [*tableaux* vs *tableaus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tableaux%2Ctableaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *tableaux* vs *tableaus* ngram]

### [*vœux* vs *vœus*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=v%C5%93ux%2Cv%C5%93us%2Cvoeux%2Cvoeus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: *vœux* vs *vœus* ngram]

## Summary

Only the French loanwords that have been around longest, and used the most, have lost their irregular inflection.  Indeed, one of the very oldest, *chapeau* is even unattested in the *chapeaux* form.

On the other hand, words that require special treatment, like *châteaux* or *nouveaux arrivés*, can be expected to retain their imported forms longer.  It may also be that people who know to use the import as an import, also know to import its irregularity: notice how 
*vœux*, *voeux*, and *voues* all occur, but never
*vœus*.  In the same way, there are no instances of *châteaus*, since if they know enough to hat the *a*, they surely know enough to *-x* the plural.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm very surprised at the prevalence of plateaux! BTW, any idea if/why all these -x plurals are pronounced—going by the dictionary—as if they're -s plurals? I'd expected them to retain their French-ness.

Comment: @coleopterist English needs a -z sound for people to hear the plural.  That -x isn’t truly silent in French, since it is sounded in liaison, like in *aux amis*.  English doesn’t make that distinction, so it is always sounded.

Comment: you should copy your comment about the pronunciation into the body of your answer for completeness and visibility.

Answer (score 4):

In American English, *none* of those words are regularly pluralized in *-x*, not even *tableaus*. (Nor *bureaus*, nor *chateaus*.) Of course, I'd also say that none of those words are "regularly" pluralized to begin with. One doesn't often need to refer to multiple tableaus or bureaus in print.

In other *-x* neux, American crossworders may be familiar with *EAUX* ("Vichy waters?"), but that's definitely a French word, not an English one. *Flambeaux* is borderline. *Beaux* appears as an adjective in *Beaux-Arts*, but that's a borrowed French phrase.

Basically, the "Frenchier" the word, the more likely I'd be to consider it pluralized in *-x*. For example, I would consider *ski chateaux* to be humorously pretentious*, but *chapeaus* to be a solecism. (If you're going to go that far out of your way to use a French word in place of *hats*, you should spell the French word correctly.)

* FWIW, Google disagrees with my personal intuition about "ski chateaus"; neither phrase is common, but "ski chateaux" is more prevalent in that tiny sample.

In all of these cases, I would expect an American-English speaker to pronounce the final *-x* as /-z/, regardless of its French pronunciation. See also [this Wikipedia talk page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AEnglish_plural#French_silent_-x_not_silent_in_English).

Comment: Different areas have different customs, but that's the first time I've even *seen* the word 'chateaus'; without authority, this may not be very helpful to OP.

Comment: You are quite incorrect about your assertion. Check the ngrams. Perhaps loltxting Merkins don’t use the *-x* form here, but the [very strong evidence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ch%C3%A2teaux%2Cch%C3%A2teaus%2Cchateaux%2Cchateaus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) is that their actual books do indeed use the *-x* form.

Comment: Thank you for the WP talk page link which is informative. Why do you believe that all AE speakers will (naturally?) pronounce the -x as /-z/?

Comment: @coleopterist Because that’s how we were taught to pronounce it.

Comment: @tchrist I admit my intuition about "chateaus" isn't authoritative. However, you'll see most of those results are about tourism in Francophone countries ("The Chateaux of Bordeaux" and so on), so it makes sense to use French spellings. Filtering to only those results which *also* include e.g. "billionaire" evens the results dramatically. In re the clearly non-French fixed phrase "ski chateau", my intuition is (statistically insignificantly) correct: Google Books reports one *ski chateaux* from 1972, two *ski chateaus* from 2003 and 2004, and one incorrect *a ski chateaux* from 2011.